# how can invoke Chrome within selenium code in a mode “Run as Different User” in java/Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how can invoke Chrome within selenium code in a mode “Run as Different User” in java/Selenium because my application windows authentication and need to open chrome with different user and launch application

Comment: What exactly do you mean  by _Run as Different User_? Necessarily you don't execute Selenium tests as a root/admin user.

Comment: iIhave automation suite and need to run from jenkins  job from build server... my applicaiton is working with logged user in the system.From jenkins we are providing service account but this service account will not directly not interact with build server(not logged in) due to some security reasons.Before run my suite need to logged into test user in browser and start exeuction(test user have application access)